# How to make jmeter script run for different session Ids without repeating the http requests

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I need to cover a use case where 10 users will be logging in and each user will create a dataset with different parameters(Like name....). Now all these http requests need to use the Unique Bearer token from each of the 10 users in the header manager. I know i can parameterize the users with CSV file. But how can i use the same http request for each of these 10 users? I mean each http request need to have a separate header manager with different bearer tokens. So is there any way i can reuse the same http request for different users. In my generate token request i can parameterize through csv. But in the subsequent request which uses the token in the header manager, how to make the same request work for different bearer tokens

[image]

Comment: What is your problem? Token in this case is thread local var, it's isolated for each thread (each user flow). I don't see any problem in your setup.

Answer (score 0):

As per [JMeter documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

> Variables are local to a thread

so the bearer token value will be different for each thread (virtual user) as each JMeter thread has its own context and set of variables which is not shared among the others

You can double check it yourself using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debug-jmeter), you will see that `access_token` variable is different for each virtual user and the [Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) request header contains correct (and different) values.